# Xrm.Page.getAttribute("").getValue() don't get actual value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I have a custom entity in CRM 2011 with a Closure Code(drop down list) and Solution(multiple lines text) fields.

Is weird what is happening, and this is that the next sentence, is not getting the actual field value:

```
var detailsSet = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("aux_solution").getValue();
```

Why this could happen?

Comment: So what is result of this? You aren't getting any value or...?? Use developer tool in IE to see what is happening here

Comment: I have debug with VS and I see that the Solution value just change when I change the value of the drop down list, if not it always take the old value that it has, taking the updated value for the drop down list.

Comment: Can you please run that command in the IE Console and paste the results here.

Comment: It gives me a null value having a string in the solution field

Comment: I don't know if you will believe me or not.. because I never have seen this behavior before, but I have realized that when the focus is still in the Solution field and I press for execute the Javascipt, it keep the old value it has, but when I move the focus on other field, it refresh the value. Now is working like it should with this update, it make sense?

Comment: What event are you firing this JavaScript on in the CRM form? The result you describe is the expected result because until you indicate you are done data-entry by leaving the field there is no event to fire and thus the underlying data value will not have been updated.

Comment: It's an event called from a custom button in the ribbon.I never have realized that was working like that. What I was doing was write and without leave the field click with mouse the button. However, now I know this behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, my problem was that the field wasn't taking the actual value because the focus was on it. Moving to another field before checking the values is how I solve this. I hope could help someone.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the object model does not get refreshed data while you have focus on the field. If you want to get the value without having to click outside you need to use the good old document.getElementById .

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option set, you should use eiter getSelectedOption() or getText()

so try

```
var detailsSet = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("aux_solution").getText();
```

For more details refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_getText)