# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null at welcomeAlert

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm new in CRM. 
I need just on the OnLoad event of the page, show a JavaScript alert message: "Welcome 'Account Name'". 
This is my simple code:

```
function welcomeAlert()
{
  var userName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();
  if(userName !== null)
  {
    alert("Welcome " + userName + "!");
  }
}
```

But I'm getting error message onLoad: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null at welcomeAlert.

If my code looking like code below everything works fine.

```
function welcomeAlert()
{
    alert("Welcome ");
}
```

Somebody can help? Maybe the attribute name is not ok. But I don't know how to check it.

Comment: So getAttribute('name') is obviously not returning anything. Since I don't know what Xrm or Page are I can't help much more specifically.

Open the debugger and put a break point at the var username line and hover over the objects to see what attributes they have. That may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xrm.Page.getAttribute("").getValue() don't get actual value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561802/xrm-page-getattribute-getvalue-dont-get-actual-value)

Comment: Does the "name" field exist in your Page?

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify the attribute `name` to make sure its in the form
2. If the field is a custom attribute then it will be having publisher name prefix ex. `new_name`
3. If the field is added in header/footer sections or BPF stages then it will be renamed like `header_name`
4. Check if it’s hidden or added multiple times in the form & use browser developer toolbar to inspect the DOM
5. You can validate like `if(formContext.getAttribute("name") != null` before accessing `getValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of CRM, `Xrm.Page` may be deprecated. Refer to [deprecation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated.)

The correct way of doing this is to use the `executionContext` object which is a parameter that can be passed to your methods by CRM. Microsoft provides an an example of how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/clientapi-form-context) but the steps are:

1. Update your method to include a new parameter: e.g. `function welcomeAlert(executionContext)`
2. Use `executionContext` to retrieve the `formContext`: e.g. `var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext()`
3. Use `formContext` as a substitute for `Xrm.Page`: e.g. `var userName = formContext.getAttribute("name").getValue();`
4. When you register this function in CRM, you need to be sure to check the **Pass execution context as first parameter** option otherwise CRM will not pass the executionContext to your function

Putting it all together, your method should look like this:

```
function welcomeAlert(executionContext)
{
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  var userName = formContext.getAttribute("name").getValue();
  if(userName !== null)
  {
    alert("Welcome " + userName + "!");
  }
}
```

Comment: I made all 4 stages, but this didn't solve the problem. Getting the same error

Comment: Is the `name` field on the form?

Comment: NO. I read this on docs.microsoft, so I thought that the attribute for Account Name is "name".
var nameValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();

Assigns the value of the Account Name field to the nameValue variable.

The right attribute for Account Name is "parentcustomerid". This code works for me. 

function welcomeAlert()
{
  var userName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentcustomerid").getValue()[0].name;
  if(userName !== null)
  {
     alert("Welcome " + userName  + "!");
  }
}

Thank you for response.

Comment: ohhh, you're not on an `Account` form - you're on a `Contact` form. That makes sense now. Well done fixing it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem!
I read this on docs.microsoft, so I thought that the attribute for Account Name is "name". `var nameValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();` 
Assigns the value of the Account Name field to the nameValue variable.

The right attribute for Account Name is "parentcustomerid". This code works for me.

```
    function welcomeAlert() 
     { 
       var userName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentcustomerid").getValue()[0].name; 
       if(userName !== null) 
       { 
         alert("Welcome " + userName + "!"); 
       } 

     }
```

Thank you all for response.

Comment: OMG, totally a different attribute. Glad you sorted it out. Since you are new to this site, a piece of helpful advice, when you post your question/problem - try to add screenshots about what you are talking about.. so the issue can be identified easily. have a good day :)